# colorprimarydark only work for the mainactivity,what should i do with it

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service android:name="com.amap.api.location.APSService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label=""/>
    <activity
        android:name=".QueryActivity"
        android:label="" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TaskListActivity"
        android:label="" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TaskWatcherActivity"
        android:label="" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailsActivity"
        android:label="" />

</application>
```

i have set the style in style:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/cpb_white</item>
</style>


<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

&style-v21:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>

    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/cpb_white</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

but only the mainactivity's status bar is in colorprimarydark,other activities' statusbar is in the color of their layout's background. so how can i make colorprimarydark work for every activity's status bar

Comment: Do you extend AppCompatActivity for all activities?

Comment: i have extends appcompatactivity for some activity,others extends activity, but only mainactivity work

Comment: activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label=""    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"   /> same like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy and useful library [for Tint Color](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) use this library in every Activity set you status color.

Comment: bu i still want to set it for only one time,i donnot understand why only the mainactivity work,maybe for i use the drawerlayout in it？

Comment: set same theme in every acitivity tag in your Manifest file

Comment: thanks, i am learning to use it.but i have thought that i have set [   <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>] in style-v21.xml, so i think if it is correct that all statusbars are in transparent. because as i change it, i can change the color of all the activities except mainactivity,mainactivity is still under the colorprimarydark

Comment: @david this helps you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in each and every activity.

I think you solve your problem.

Comment: i have tried it, but it doesnot work. But now i think '<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>' in style-v21.xml make all the activities' status bar to be transparent, but drawlayout in mainactivity producted by android studio automaticly can draw a view that is in colorprimarydark under the location of status bar, so the left side navigation can be set above the toolbar&view in colorprimarydark, and under the subtranslucent status bar.but i don't know if it is true...

Answer (score 0):

finally, i used the library for Tint Color to solve the problem, p.s.thasks to Jhaman Das.

And i found that the attr of statusBarColor would cover the effect of colorpromarydark, it is the drawlayout that can have the ideal effect. willing to get further discussion on this problem.